# Shrinking and Expanding objects in a CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory

In a conformal field theory, is it possible to construct a machine that shrinks or expands objects?

Comment: What do you mean by "machine"? I have never heard about any "machines" in (conformal) field theory ...?

Comment: I mean that engineers could build a device that shrinks or expands objects. It is like asking what kind of machines,  technologies or computers one can construct in quantum theory or electromagnetism.